# how to send email from android emulator without using intents?

Tags: android

I have tried with javaApi to send email.It is working well.but I need to send email without giving password and also not only to gmail but yahoo and others such as hotmail,rediff etc..how can I acheive this?pls give some ideas..

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using bundle intent.An use it in another activity.
try this code:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                String aEmailList[] = {email.getText().toString()};
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."), REQUEST_EMAIL);
```